# ruby file not created new when "created" multiple times in an each loop

Tags: ruby, file

I try to run a regex over the files of some subfolder. Obviously this leads to unwanted behaviour. It seems that ruby doesn't create the temporary file new but that it would just re-open and continue. Every time I run the script the whole file (or multiple files?) seem to be appended and grow and grow and grow.

The first step of my strategy is like follows

1. I discover the files in the subdirectories via Dir.glob, save the full_paths in an array and read the files into a buffer file in an each loop.
2. I close the file and run the regex over the buffer

The second step consists of

1. in another each loop over the array consisting of the full-paths of the files I want to manipulate,
2. I create a temporary file in the same folder. every time with the same name,
3. delete the original file,
4. write the regex'ed buffer into the temporary file,
5. rename the temporary file after the original file.

So:
In the same directory as the original file

```
fh2 = File.new(temp_filename, "w:UTF-8")
count = fh2.write(file_buffer)
puts "That was #{count} bytes of data to #{temp_filename}"
fh2.close
```

`count` grows continuously greater with each file that is manipulated/created this way.

Could it be, that it doesn't create a fresh temp-file because of the same file_handle, the same name or the `w`-option together with `File.new`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake. I didn't empty the buffer (and the buffer isn't local to a block !)

```
# load file in buffer
fh = File.open(file,"r+:UTF-8")

while (line = fh.gets) 
file_buffer += line
end

fh.close
```

The thread can be closed. Sorry for wasting your time.